# Call VBA UDF across different VBAProjects

Tags: excel, vba

I am developing an Excel Add-in to help harmonize calculations done by my coworkers. It is basically a collection of industry-specific UDFs bundled together in regular and class modules.

There are a number of functions that are highly specialized and are used in only specific applications. As such, these functions would be included as a module in the individual workbooks where they will be used.

I would like to be able to re-use several "helper" functions from the Add-in to simplify these "external" functions. As near as I can tell, UDFs are not available across VBAProjects. I've tried to add a reference to the Add-In, but while the Add-in is loaded, Excel complains that

"Name conflicts with existing module, project, or object library"

which makes sense. It's trying to add something with the same name.

Removing the add-in and only adding it as a reference seems to give the desired result (workbook-specific UDFs can call add-in UDFs and Subs), but it only appears to work for that specific workbook.

Is there a way to call UDFs across separate VBAProjects?

Comment: You can have shared functions in an addin. Each VBA project that wants to use the addin must have a reference to it. You can have several projects opened at the same time all of which have a reference to the same addin.

Comment: "Name conflicts with existing module, project, or object library" this happens, as your addin code will have default Project Name VBAProject, so renaming that to something else will stop this

Comment: @Nathan_Sav, I have tried renaming the VBAProject, but the result is the same. I assumed the issue is that the "referenced" version has the same name as the "add-in" version as they are the same file in the same location.

Answer (score 0):

Additional trial-and-error testing has revealed the error to me: I was attempting to add a reference to the add-in to itself, which would presumably be recursive and cause issues.

Selecting a module in the specific workbook allowed me to add a reference to the add-in and successfully use the functions it contains.